# What is the best way async in services angular

Tags: angularjs

I have two case like this :

Case 1 :

services

```
function login(data) {
return $http.post('/api/authenticate',data)
}
```

controller

```
vm.login = function() { 
                services.login(vm.data)
                        .then(function(response) {
                        vm.datas= response.data;
                        });
                }
```

Case 2

services

```
function login(data) {
        return $http.post('/api/authenticate',data).then(function(data) {
                        return data.data;
                    });
                };
```

Controller

```
vm.login = function() {
                services.login(data)
                        .then(function(response) {
                        vm.data= response
                        });
                }
```

Two case all work . But I want ask , what is better beetween 2 case above and why ?

Comment: why you dont like it @lin :(

Comment: interesting question .I'm not sure but  I think what you mean is depending on different case
@lin